# Laravel print array in blade php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to show an array in my .blade.php, but it does not work properly so my controller looks like this:

```
class WatchController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $watchFolderPath = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Pro\\rec\\';
        $watchFolder     = $this->dirToArray($watchFolderPath);
        return view('watch.new')->with('watchFolder', $watchFolder);
    }

    # Get Directories of Path as Array
    function dirToArray($dir) {

        $result = array();

        $cdir = scandir($dir);

        foreach ($cdir as $key => $value)
        {
            if (!in_array($value,array(".","..")))
            {
                if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value))
                {
                    $result[$value] = $this->dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);
                }
                else
                {
                    $result[] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

And inside my blade I just tried to call it like this:

```
{{ $watchFolder }}
```

but it did not work, I get the following error:

> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Edit:
The array I get shows all Folders/Files with subfolder in a directory.
(used dd())

Currently it looks like this:

```
array:6 [▼
  123123 => array:2 [▼
    "subfolder1" => array:1 [▼
      0 => "video.mpg"
    ]
    "subfolder2" => array:1 [▶]
  ]
  789 => array:2 [▶]
  "folder1" => array:2 [▶]
  "folder2" => array:2 [▶]
  "folder3" => array:2 [▶]
  "folder1" => []
]
```

Comment: you need to loop over the items, like `@foreach` just read the blade manual

Comment: Either `{{ print_r($array, true) }}` or `{!! dd($array) !!}` will help you :)

Comment: I want to show it in my blade beautifully later on..

Comment: So then why haven't you accepted Alexey's answer?

Comment: are you even reading the comments?

Comment: I've answered, with my answer and Alexey's answer you have everything you need - if you still can't work it out then that's tough; we've spoon fed you enough.

Comment: still no answer to my comment.

Comment: What comment? there are lot's none of which ask a specific question - why not improve your question to be 100% clear as to what you want to achieve, what you have done so far and what you're not able to do...

Comment: As a future advice I would suggest you to read the comments to have a better understanding.

Answer (score 35):

To just output the array in blade for debugging purposes:

```
        @php
            var_dump($arr);
        @endphp
```

Then use a foreach loop as mentioned.

Answer (score 13):

From your question it appears as if you want to output the *array* for debugging purposes which as I have commented you can simply use `<?php` and `?>` tags within your blade templates.

```
<?php dd($array); ?>
```

However, blade has a raw output tag pair which is `{!!` and `!!}`.

Once you're ready to display the output of your directory structure you should assign it to your view.

There are 2 quick ways of using it either with Reflection; inside your controller:

```
class WatchController extends Controller
{
    public function index(\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem $filesystem)
    {
        $files = $filesystem->allFiles($watchFolderPath);

        // Your code.

        return view('name', ['files' => $files]);
    }
}
```

Or to call it from the [container](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php):

```
class WatchController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $files = app('files')->allFiles($watchFolderPath);

        // Your code.

        return view('name', ['files' => $files]);
    }
}
```

---

Also you **should** be using the [Filesystem](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php), there is no need to reinvent the wheel – You should [read the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/).

Answer (score 8):

You should use [`@foreach`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#control-structures):

```
@foreach ($watchFolder as $key => $value)
    Key: {{ $key }}    
    Value: {{ $value }} 
@endforeach
```

Or

```
@foreach ($watchFolder as $w)
    {{ $w->name }}    
@endforeach
```

Comment: how would you print out all values of the array?

Comment: If you're asking how to print out all values for debugging, you could try to use `dd($watchFolder);` in your controller or `{{ dd($watchFolder); }}` in your view. If you're asking how to print out array values in profuction, look at the code in my answer.

Comment: does not work I get following error:ErrorException in helpers.php line 469:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: That's because you're building complicated array, please post your array structure example in your question, so we could be able to help you.

Comment: In blade `{{` and `}}` are replacements for `<?php echo` and `?>` and are also parsed through `e()` for escaping bad things.  Therefore it would need the _literal_ tags for HTML output or RAW php; `{!!` and `!!}` or `<?php` and `?>` are also free to use inside a blade template (although frowned upon).

Answer (score 5):

For those that might come looking...like me

```
echo implode("\n",$array);
```

else if its multidimensional array

```
echo implode("\n",array_collapse($array));
```

Answer (score 3):

To output your `$watchFolder` array in a blade file, you can use the following method:

```
<pre><code>{{ json_encode($watchFolder, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) }}</code></pre>
```

This will display a nicely formatted JSON version of your array and make it more readable:

```
{
    "123123": {
        "subfolder1": [
            "video.mpg"
        ],
        "subfolder2": []
    },
    "789": [],
    "folder1": [],
    "folder2": [],
    "folder3": []
}
```

You can also remove the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` if you only need to display it in a single line:

```
{"123123":{"subfolder1":["video.mpg"],"subfolder2":[]},"789":[],"folder1":[],"folder2":[],"folder3":[]}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may simply use :

```
@dump($arr)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.